# GraphQL unable to resolve nested object property

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, graphql

I am trying to return a graphQL query with some nested property objects in a list. Everything seems to check out, but am getting null values.

Expected datastructure response (more detail on structure [here](https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api/subscriptions#list_subscriptions)):

```
//Return a GraphQLList type of all objects :    
[
    {
        "subscription" : {

        },
        "customer" : {

        },
    },
]
```

the query: `{ subscriptions { subscription { id customer_id } } }`

GraphQL Query Object:

```
var Query = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: 'Root of the Schema',
    fields: {
        subscriptions: {
            type: new graphQL.GraphQLList(SubscriptionsList),
            args : {
                customer_name: { type: graphQL.GraphQLString },
                customer_id: { type: graphQL.GraphQLString }
            },
            resolve : function (source, args) {
                return getSubscriptions().then(function (res) {
                    // Shows that data is returned
                    console.log('Data: ', res.list);

                    return res.list;
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    return err;
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Which expects to return type `GraphQLList` of `SubscriptionsList`:

```
var SubscriptionsList = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name : 'SubscriptionObj',
    description : 'stuff',
    fields : function () {
        return {
            subscription : {
                type : Subscription,
                resolve : function (subscription) {
                    return  subscription;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Which should resolve the nested field property:

```
var Subscription = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name : 'Subscription',
    description : 'stuff',
    fields : function () {
        return {
            id: {type: graphQL.GraphQLString},
            customer_id: {type: graphQL.GraphQLString}
        }
    }
});
```

**Console.log(res.list) Output (from Query):** I am definitely getting the data and structure I expect:

```
[ { subscription: 
     { id: 'cbdemo_lloyd-sub2',
       customer_id: 'cbdemo_lloyd',
       plan_id: 'cbdemo_nuts',
       addons: [Object],
       due_invoices_count: 0,
       shipping_address: [Object] },
    customer: {
       ...
    }
  },
  {...}
]
```

**GraphQL Query Output:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "subscription": {
          "id": null,
          "customer_id": null
        }
      },
      {
        "subscription": {
          "id": null,
          "customer_id": null
        }
      },
```

---

**EDIT** Not really necessary, but here is the `getSubscriptions()` API call that returns a promise:

```
function getSubscriptions() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        chargebee.subscription.list({
            limit : 5,
            "plan_id[is_not]" : "basic",
            "status[is]" : "active",
            "sort_by[asc]" : "created_at"
        }).request(function(error,result){
            if (error) return reject(error);
            return resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are getting abit confused,
Basiclly, when you set

```
new graphQL.GraphQLList(SubscriptionsList),
```

this is already a list.
which means what you really meant is

```
new graphQL.GraphQLList(Subscription),
```

Next, your subscription object does not contain any resolve logic,
so i would expect it to be something like this:

```
var Subscription = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
    name : 'Subscription',
    description : 'stuff',
    fields : function () {
        return {
            id: {
                   type: graphQL.GraphQLString,
                   resolve: function(subscription) {
                       return subscription.subscription.id;
                   }
            },
            customer_id: {
                   type: graphQL.GraphQLString,
                   resolve: function(subscription) {
                       return subscription.subscription.customer_id;
                   }
            },
        }
    }
});
```

What basically happens under the hood, is that GraphQL will resolve each javascript object in the list provided, using the Subscription object.
each resolver there will get the javascript object as the first value,
and return the basic value from it.

Comment: small tip, if you will add console.log under the resolvers of Subscription, you should be able to see each obejct in the list just to make sure you are in the right direction

Comment: Why do I need to resolve the `id` and `customer_id`? Isn't my `getSubscriptions()` method already resolving when it returns its response? Why does GraphQL need to resolve those fields?

Comment: GraphQL doesn't know how to handle objects. Only the types that you have defined for it. basically you are declaring a new type `Subscription` , and then you describe how each field is resolved. this is actually one of the powers of GraphQL since 1 Object doesn't have to be identical the database layer object. more information can be found [here](http://graphql.org/docs/api-reference-type-system/#graphqlobjecttype)

Answer (score 2):

I think the resolver in your SubscriptionsList has to return `subscription.subscription`. I would consider changing the name of subscriptionsList, because it's quite confusing.

The way I see it, you should just have a GraphQLList(Subscription) and remove that extra level of nesting. Either that, or call the thing that contains a subscription and a customer something else.

Answer (score 1):

According to your post, `res.list` shows the following:

```
// listing #1
[
  { 
    subscription: {
      id: 'cbdemo_lloyd-sub2',
      customer_id: 'cbdemo_lloyd',
      plan_id: 'cbdemo_nuts',
      addons: [Object],
      due_invoices_count: 0,
      shipping_address: [Object] },
      customer: {
        ...
      }
  },
  {...}
]
```

Now, the above result corresponds to `subscriptions` field in your `Query`, which is a list of `SubscriptionsList`. Therefore, value of a `SubscriptionsList` will be item from the above listing #1:

```
// listing #2
{
  subscription: {
    id: 'cbdemo_lloyd-sub2',
    customer_id: 'cbdemo_lloyd',
    plan_id: 'cbdemo_nuts',
    addons: [Object],
    due_invoices_count: 0,
    shipping_address: [Object] },
    customer: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

In `SubscriptionsList` type, you have a field `subscription`. Its resolve function returns whatever it gets. So the field `subscription` remains the same as listing #2.

While resolving `subscription` field (type `Subscription`), it looks for `id` and `customer_id` properties in object shown in listing #2. But that object has only `subscription` property. Therefore, `id` and `customer_id` fields receive `null` values.

Thus, the problem is in the resolve function of `subscription` field. Its input is object in listing #2 and its output should be the object in the following listing #3:

```
// listing #3
{
  id: 'cbdemo_lloyd-sub2',
  customer_id: 'cbdemo_lloyd',
  plan_id: 'cbdemo_nuts',
  addons: [Object],
  due_invoices_count: 0,
  shipping_address: [Object] },
  customer: {
    ...
  }
}
```

To get the object in listing #3, change in your `SubscriptionsList` type:

```
subscription : {
    type : Subscription,
    resolve : function (item) { // item is listing #2
        return  item.subscription; // item.subscription is listing #3
    }
}
```

On a different note, the GraphQL object type `SubscriptionsList` is actually unnecessary here and made the whole thing complicated. The whole design will become a lot simpler without it.